# automatic object naming java

Tags: java

I new to java and I have been trying to code a method that allow me to create and declare an object and add it to my array list automatically.

```
public static void 

public static int objectCreate(String a, ArrayList<pet> list,int x)
{
pet pets= new pet ("pet"+ x);
pet pets.getName() = new pet("dog",10,"healthy");
list.add(pet.getName());
x++;
return x
}
```

String a is the pet's name and i'm trying to make it so that everytime i call this method, it will create an object with a different name. For instance, the second time i call this name, it would create an object called pet2 and so on and so forth. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Besides the *syntax/compiler errors*, what's the problem? Hint: you probably don't want to pass in `x` as a parameter or increment the [otherwise unused] `a` member. (And please, fix the syntax/compiler errors *before* trying to work on anything else .. it'll be much more productive that way.)

Comment: Hint for why `x++` is still useless (while continuing to ignoring the blatant errors): read up on how *values* are passed in Java.

Comment: Okay, -1. Stop randomly changing the post. **Fix the compiler errors and post only compiling code** (unless the question is about a *specific* compiler error). Then explain "what doesn't work"; if the title can't be made general then it means the problem isn't well enough defined.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a error stating that pets is already defined, however I'm trying to get create an object with the name (say x is 1), therefore the name is pet1.

Comment: Lets say valid code is posted. As far as the principle, perhaps the idea is to use a "static field"? Otherwise, the idea behind this approach will work if you *correctly use the return value of the **non-compiling** function* above on subsequent invocations.

Comment: ok, I am not really able to understand what you just said, as I have limited understanding in this area, I'll read up on static and return values. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).